What is the zero subscheme in Bertini's type Theorem
I am recently study the Bertini's type Theorem in the book "Joins and Intersections". In the Page 109, Theorem 3.4.8, the authors stated as follows:"Let $K$ be a fixed field and assume that the property $P$ satisfies 3.4.7(1), (2). Let $X$, $\mathcal{L}$, $s_1,...,s_n$ be as in 3.4.3 and assume that $X$ satisfies $P$. Then $P$ also holds for the generic hyperplane section $X_{\alpha}:=V(\sum_i\alpha_is_i), \alpha\in K^n$."
It seems that the authors didn't clearly define the Notaion $V(\sum_i\alpha_is_i)$. My question is what it means $V(\sum_i\alpha_is_i)$?
(I notice that in [Sta, 0G47] they also state a similar Theorem and they define the zero subscheme $Z(s)$ in [Sta, 02OQ], however I am not sure their definitions are same.)

This is the only reasonable definition of the zero scheme.
